# What is cluster and node in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, nodes, concept

About RabbitMQ two concept is unknow to me, `cluster` and `node` ? what is different between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A RabbitMQ **node** is the basic "message broker" service (process running on a server) which provides core RabbitMQ features such as exchanges, virtual hosts, queues, etc. You need at least one RabbitMQ node to be up-and-running, to use RabbitMQ.

---

A RabbitMQ **cluster** is simply a grouping of one or more RabbitMQ nodes. From the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html), a cluster is:

> "*a logical grouping of one or several nodes, each sharing users, virtual hosts, queues, exchanges, bindings, runtime parameters and other distributed state.*".

Why can it be useful to place nodes in a cluster? Again from the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/distributed.html):

> Clustering nodes can help improve availability, data safety of queue contents and sustain more concurrent client connections.

So, a cluster of nodes gives you more flexibility (than a single node), about how you design and provide your overall RabbitMQ services.

---

The terms "node" and "cluster" are not specific to RabbitMQ - they are fairly generic terms, used much more widely than just for RabbitMQ.